# Get tag of latest git commit

Tags: git, tags

I want to find the tag of the last commit if it is present.  So far I have found only the option to get the last tag inside all of the tags..

But I want to know if there is a tag on the last commit or no tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[edit] @phd pointed out that `git tag` has a [`--points-at`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#Documentation/git-tag.txt---points-atltobjectgt) option, which makes for a nicer command :

```
git tag --points-at HEAD
```

---

*my initial answer :*

You can use the `--points-at` option of `git for-each-ref` :

```
git for-each-ref --points-at=HEAD
```

To display only the tag name, and limit the searched refs to tag  :

```
git for-each-ref --points-at=HEAD --format="%(refname:lstrip=2)" refs/tags
```

Comment: [`git tag --points-at @`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#Documentation/git-tag.txt---points-atltobjectgt)

Comment: Ow... yes this is way better than my early ramblings. Nice.